# Asymptotic behaviour of the intersection volume of balls with the same radius

Tags: asymptotics, euclidean-geometry, volume, spherical-geometry, convex-geometry

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be two fixed points. Is there an easy proof of the fact that 
$$A(r):=\frac{ \text{Vol}(B(x,r) \cap  B(y,r))}{\text{Vol}(B(x,r))}$$
tends to $1$ when $r \to \infty$. I measure volumes via the standard Lebesgue measure.

> I know that there are formulas for the volumes inscribed in spherical caps, but I wonder if there is an easier way to derive the asymptotic result without going through the exact formulas. Since I only care about the asymptotic behaviour when $r \to \infty$, this might be doable in a more elementary way.

An alternative equivalent formulation, which might seem more intuitive is the following: Set

$$B(r):=\frac{ \text{Vol}(B(x,r) \setminus B(y,r))}{\text{Vol}(B(x,r))}$$

Then $B(r)$ tends to zero when $r \to \infty$, as the distance between the points $|x-y|$ becomes negligible compared to the radius $r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d =|x-y|$, then for $r \gt d$, $$B(x,r) \setminus B(y,r)\subseteq B(x,r) \setminus B(x,r - d)$$

So $$\text{Vol}(B(x,r) \setminus B(y,r)) \le \text{Vol}(B(x,r) \setminus B(x,r - d)) = C(r^n - (r-d)^n)$$ for some constant $C$. Thus
$$B(r) \le \frac {C(r^n - (r-d)^n)}{Cr^n} = O\left(\frac 1r\right)$$
and therefore goes to $0$ as $r \to \infty$.